# Pandas value_counts() alternative for a range of values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been using value_count() to get the counts of unique values in individual rows of dataframe by doing the following:

```py
data.iloc[i,2:-1].value_counts()
```

Is it possible to do that for a range of rows? I tried the following, but it didn't work, is it just printed out the range that I specified instead of counting the unique values:

```py
data.iloc[0:5,2:-1].value_counts()
```

I would like a similar kind of output (a Series) that I can loop through using .items()

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)?

Comment: Does this work?  `df.iloc[np.r_[0:5, 2:-1]].value_counts()`  I'd test but you didn't sample data.

Comment: `data.iloc[0:5,2:-1].value_counts()` should work, I tried on a small df I have and it was ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `apply`:

```
data.iloc[0:5, 2:-1].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1)
```

But that would give you value counts *for each row*. So you would get a dataframe. Now if you want to count values in the whole data section, you can `stack`:

```
data.iloc[0:5, 2:-1].stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: This worked for me. `stack()` was what I was missing. Using it without stack (as I had tried before and as was suggested in the comments), didn't work. Thanks for your help